# Error While Cleaning Facebook SDK Project

Tags: java, android, eclipse, facebook

Everytime I click Project -> Clean on the FacebookSDK Project I receive the error

"Errors running Android Package Builder on project FacebookSDK. Problems encountered while deleting resources. Could not delete 'C:\Users\$$$\Downloads\facebook-android-sdk-3.0.1\facebook-android-sdk-3.0.1\facebook\bin\facebooksdk.jar' "

I am not sure as to why the project would even want to delete this jar Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Close eclipse and open it again.
It's ok for eclipse to try to delete this on clean, it will generate it again.